# How to prevent my service from caching data in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm retrieving data through a get request and displaying them in a Table, if I refresh the page I'll always have the request happening the way I want it to, but if change the route and come back to the table page, it will get data cached from the first service, because of this, if I delete an item, it disappears from the table. If I change routes, the item will comeback, since the cached data still has the item I deleted. Thanks in advance!

This is the request, it's executed on NgOnInit()

```
getSolicitacoes():Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(URL_API + '/solicitacao', httpOptionsUno);
  }
```

This how I get and delete the data displayed in the table

```
getSolicitacoes() {
    this.solicitacaoService.getSolicitacoes().subscribe( data => {
      this.solicitacoes = data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  apagarSolicitacao(id, index) {
      this.solicitacaoService.deleteSolicitacao(id).subscribe(data => {
        this.toast.success('Solicitação deletada com sucesso!');
        this.solicitacoes.splice(index,1);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.toast.error('Não foi possível deletar a solicitação!');
      },
      () => this.rerender()
      )
    }
```

I've already tried adding meta tags to my html with cache-control, pragma and expires headers.
I'm sorry for my english, tried to find a solution on my language but it's been a struggle.

Comment: can you share the logic where you and declared table and deleting entries from it.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh added to the post

Comment: Just as a side note, you should not post questions with Spanish on var names, it is less readable for English speakers.

Comment: Please post the relevant code from the service, it seems like you are just getting what you ask for (a data from the server).

Also, please write which code happens where - it will make helping you easier.
Thank you!

Comment: @Maayao When I refresh the page I get what I want from the server, but when I change routes and come back to the table, the data loaded is the cache from the first request. This is why the items I deleted and that disappeared from the table pop back up.

Comment: @placementw The thing is, I do not think it's the cache, it looks like you are making a request *again* and then display the results. We can't really know, unless you provide the code of the service and the component, along with onInit and so. I will look at it if you update the question.

Comment: @Maayao going for lunch right now, I'll post the whole thing when I come back, just have in mind that if it was making a request again, it wouldn't contain the deleted items, since they don't exist anymore on my database, and they actually go away when I refresh the page and the request happens again

Comment: hi @placementw you can place call to `getSolicitacoes()` in your `ngOnInit()` method in component.ts file, in that case every time you come back to the page from another route , it will fetch the latest data from API

Comment: try replacing "this.solicitacoes.splice(index,1)" with "this.solicitacoes = this.solicitacoes.filter(s => s.id !== id)"